# Where to begin reading SQLite source code?

Tags: c, sqlite, open-source

I want to understand how sqlite is implemented. And, want to read the source code( I have already downloaded the source). Which part of the code I should start looking at?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The SQLite [documentation page](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) has a great section named **SQLite Technical/Design Documentation** with articles on the internals of SQLite. I think it's essential to read and understand those before you start reading the source code itself.

There are many gems there, but the most interesting for you is probably [Architecture of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/arch.html), as its description says:

> An architectural overview of the
>   SQLite library, useful for those who
>   want to hack the code.

That page contains a nice block diagram of SQLite's code:

[image]

And then explains where in the source to find the implementation of each such block.

---

Another great resource (linked from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/books.html)) is the Oreilly mini-book ("Short Cut") named "Inside SQLite" which goes into the design and code of SQLite to explain how it works.

Comment: The Second Edition of that book was published in 2015, named "SQLite Database System Design and Implementation" from the same author.