# Data-structure to store database record

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to store employees record. I don't want to use any external libraries or framework. I am trying to build the data structure from scratch.

There will be three fields,

```
EmployeeName
Age
Salary
```

We also want to query like,

```
Get all the salary where EmployeeName = "Bill"
Get all the EmployeeName where salary > 2000
Get all the Salary where age='50'
```

I am open to use any language but not any built-in package. What is the recommended data-structure to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the purpose of this exercise is self-education.

If so, [Where to begin reading SQLite source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801664/where-to-begin-reading-sqlite-source-code) is a great place to start reading to understand how this kind of software can be built.

If you really want to roll your own, I would suggest storing your data in an array of structs/objects/dictionaries (what they are called will depend on your language), hidden behind an object so that your insert/update/delete methods on the table go through well-defined access functions.  Your operations can be implemented inefficiently with `grep`, `filter`, etc depending on your language.   In addition to the obvious fields, include `deleted` as a field.  That way you can just update that to delete a record, rather than try to modify the table.

To make them more efficient, read through https://cstack.github.io/db_tutorial/parts/part7.html for how to write a b-tree.  Then create a b-tree mapping `EmployeeName` to the list of indexes of records with that name, ditto for `age` and `salary`.  Now modify the access methods to update the indexes for those fields when you modify the table.  Your searches can now go through the b-tree to find the indexes of the records that you want, and then you can look in the table for them.

This is massively simplified compared to what a database gives you, but you're on your way to understanding how databases work.  Both in terms of why they scale, and also why they aren't magically fast.